# Excel giving #Value! error when attempting to sum up indirect cells

Tags: excel

I have a set of data in column D whose values are summed up as:

```
=DOLLAR(B2*(C2))
=DOLLAR(B3*(C3))
=DOLLAR(B4*(C4))
=DOLLAR(B5*(C5))
```

etc, etc

At the bottom of this I want to sum them all up like so:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(D2:D10))
```

But this results in a #Value! error.

If I use

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("D2:D10"))
```

I get $0, likewise if I just try =SUM(D2:D10)

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error I found out the cause of the issue was the DOLLAR function in the D column functions.

I'm not sure why but removing that even made =SUM(D2:D10) work.

Comment: The DOLLAR() function converts the number to text and puts the `$` in front.  You cannot sum a text.  If you want the `$` in front use the cell format to format the number.  It will leave it as a number.